# create List in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have class Liter, that defined here:

```
data Liter = Book { title :: String, author :: String, year :: Int}
           | Magaz { title :: String, month :: Int, year :: Int}
             deriving (Eq, Show)
```

How create a function, `getTitles`, which takes a `[Liter]` and returns a `[String]` of names.

Comment: It's `map title`. Reading just the beginning of almost any Haskell introductory tutorial would have provided you the answer. Please show some effort before posting questions on SO.

Comment: Combining sum types with records is dangerous: `month (Book "foo" "bar" 1)` will happily compile and give a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getTitles :: [Liter] -> [String]
getTitles = map title
```